# AngularJS 1.6.8: Form data not submitting and so hence unable to save it to localStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-1.6, angularjs-forms

I have a contact form. On submission, it displays a success message and it should store that data to `$localStorage`.

But, Form data not is not submitting as I do not see submitted form data in response under network in dev tools and hence I am unable to save it to `$localStorage`.

below is the code for respective files.
[link to plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/qvIblj7m3NXT1NIkKtsU/)
`contact.html`

```
<div ngController="contactController as vm">
        <div class="heading text-center">
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form class="needs-validation" id="contactForm" novalidate method="post" name="vm.contactForm" ng-submit="saveform()">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="validationTooltip01" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltipName" placeholder="Name" ng-model="vm.name" required>
                    <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                        Please enter your full name. 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="validationTooltipEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="validationTooltipUsernamePrepend">@</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="validationTooltipEmail" placeholder="Email" 
                    aria-describedby="validationTooltipUsernamePrepend" ng-model="vm.email" required>
                    <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                        Please choose a valid email.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="validationTooltip03" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Query</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltipQuery" ng-model="vm.query" placeholder="Query" required>
                    <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                        Please write your Query.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group offset-md-5">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="homebtn" ng-click="navigate ('home')">Home</button>  
            </div>
          </form>
          <span data-ng-bind="Message" ng-hide="hideMessage" class="sucessMsg"></span>
    </div>
</div
```

`contact.component.js`

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .component('contactComponent', {
  restrict: 'E',
  $scope:{},    
  templateUrl:'contact/contact.html',
  controller: contactController,
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  factory:'userService',
  $rootscope:{}
});

function contactController($scope, $state,userService) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.saveform = function(){
    var name= vm.name;
    var email= vm.email;
    var query= vm.query;
    console.log(name);
    console.log(email);
    console.log(query);



    $scope.hideMessage = false;
    $scope.Message = "Your query has been successfully submitted.";

    $scope.user = userService;
  };

  $scope.navigate = function(home){
    $state.go(home)
  };

};

//localStorage code

function userService(saveform) {
  var service = {
    model: {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        query:''
    },
    SaveState: function () {
        sessionStorage.userService = angular.toJson(service.model);
    },
    RestoreState: function () {
        service.model = angular.fromJson(sessionStorage.userService);
    }
  }
  $rootScope.$on("savestate", service.SaveState);
  $rootScope.$on("restorestate", service.RestoreState);
  return service;

  $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
    if (sessionStorage.restorestate == "true") {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('restorestate'); //let everything know we need to restore state
        sessionStorage.restorestate = false;
    }
  });
  //let everthing know that we need to save state now.
  window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('savestate');
  };
};
```

There are no errors in console.

Comment: Can you put your entire code at one place(ie Fiddle, codepen) . Where we can execute it.

Comment: Shouldn't ngController be ng-controller?

Comment: @HimanshuArora9419 I have added a link to codepen. please have a look.

Comment: @Vivz I first tried with `ng-controller` but it didn't worked. So, then I changed it to `ngController`.

Comment: I deleted what I thought was the answer as there's far more going on here.  You're using controllerAs, so there should be no need to inject $scope, or copy values from vm/this -> $scope.  Your references in your template should then all point at your controllerAs alias (i.e. `vm`).

However, I'm not sure what you're expecting to see.  Your saveform method doesn't seem to do very much - it doesn't even use your userService?

Comment: @natwallbank thanks for responding. I am new to angular 1.6.8 and there are whole bunch of confusion. Sorry for being a noob, but could you please point me in right direction and put the right code or right way.. thanks

Comment: @NaumanTanwir if you can create a Plunkr, or similar, I can happily take a look later on today.

It looks as though your component definition is a bit wrong and you've tried to mix in the definition of a factory / service too.

Comment: There's some good styleguide links around this stuff, e.g.

https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide#components (seems to have been updated to ES2015 since I last looked at it)
https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-1-5-components-app (example component-based app, with services)

Comment: Here's another one: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Comment: @natwallbank I do have linked a CODEPEN in the description. please have a look.

Comment: @natwallbank here is the to a codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WMQvXw

Comment: Here you go, this should hopefully be enough to get you started: https://plnkr.co/edit/AVKTGkWv1zbOHa49piSQ

Comment: I based the above on your original Plunkr but noticed that you hadn't really loaded Angular at all (see the new version of script.js where it declares the angular module - this is referenced via the ng-app attribute in index.html)

Comment: I split out the functionality into its own component, so that component is just dropped into index.html as <contact-us></contact-us>.  You should see that when you submit the form, those details are persisted to session storage.   Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help. makes sense now.

Comment: No problem, glad it was useful.

Comment: @natwallbank I hope you wouldn't mind if use this `plunker` for further references as I may need it to link on some queries in near future

Comment: @Nauman Of course not - use it however you need.